# In a SQL Server table how do I filter records based on JSON search on a column having JSON values

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a challenge while filtering records in a SQL Server 2017 table which has a VARCHAR column having JSON type values:

Sample table rows with JSON column values:

```
Row # 1. {"Department":["QA"]}   
Row # 2. {"Department":["DEV","QA"]}    
Row # 3. {"Group":["Group 2","Group 12"],"Cluster":[Cluster 11"],"Vertical": 
    ["XYZ"],"Department":["QAT"]}          
Row # 4. {"Group":["Group 20"],"Cluster":[Cluster 11"],"Vertical":["XYZ"],"Department":["QAT"]}
```

Now I need to filter records from this table based on an input parameter which can be in the following format:

Sample JSON input parameter to query:

```
1. `'{"Department":["QA"]}'` -> This should return Row # 1 as well as Row # 2.   
2. `'{"Group":["Group 2"]}'` -> This should return only Row # 3.
```

So the search should be like if the column value contains "any available json tag with any matching value" then return those matching records.

---

Note - This is exactly similar to PostgreSQL jsonb as shown below:
PostgreSQL filter clause:

```
TableName.JSONColumnName @> '{"Department":["QA"]}'::jsonb
```

---

By researching on internet I found OPENJSON capability that is available in SQL Server which works as below.

OPENJSON sample example:

```
SELECT * FROM
tbl_Name UA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(UA.JSONColumnTags)
WITH ([Department] NVARCHAR(500) '$.Department', [Market] NVARCHAR(300) '$.Market', [Group] NVARCHAR(300) '$.Group'       
   ) AS OT
WHERE
OT.Department in ('X','Y','Z')
and OT.Market in ('A','B','C')
```

But the problem with this approach is that if in future there is a need to support any new tag in JSON (like 'Area'), that will also need to be added to every stored procedure where this logic is implemented.

Is there any existing SQL Server 2017 capability I am missing or any dynamic way to implement the same?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a process to flatten all of your JSON data before querying. This way you can maintain 1 process to extract, and your devs don't have to update their queries to do so. They can query the "extracted" tables.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Seems you mean to flatten JSON something like below:

Comment: Row ID   Tag  Value
    1          Group  QA
    2          Group  DEV
    2          Group  QA

and then flatten the input parameter too as that is also dynamic and may cotain more than one tags with muliple values.
Once both are done, then I perform a INNER join between these two tables to retrieve correct Row IDs. 
I can give it a try, though this approach seems bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I could think of as an option when using OPENJSON would be break down your search string into its key value pair, break down your table that is storing the json you want to search into its key value pair and join.

There would be limitations to be aware of:

1. This solution would not work with nested arrays in your json
2. The search would be OR not AND.  Meaning if I passed in multiple "Department" I was searching for, like '{"Department":["QA", "DEV"]}', it would return the rows with either of the values, not those that only contained both.

Here's a working example:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [TestData] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
--Load Test Data
INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [TestData]
                      )
VALUES ( '{"Department":["QA"]}' )
     , ( '{"Department":["DEV","QA"]}' )
     , ( '{"Group":["Group 2","Group 12"],"Cluster":["Cluster 11"],"Vertical": ["XYZ"],"Department":["QAT"]}' )
     , ( '{"Group":["Group 20"],"Cluster":["Cluster 11"],"Vertical":["XYZ"],"Department":["QAT"]}' );

--Here is the value we are searching for
DECLARE @SeachJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Department":["QA"]}';

DECLARE @SearchJson TABLE
    (
        [Key] NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

--Load the search value into a temp table as its key\value pair.
INSERT INTO @SearchJson (
                            [Key]
                          , [Value]
                        )
            SELECT      [a].[Key]
                      , [b].[Value]
            FROM        OPENJSON(@SeachJson) [a]
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([a].[Value]) [b];

--Break down TestData into its key\value pair and then join back to the search table.
SELECT     [TestData].[TestData]
FROM       (
               SELECT      [a].[TestData]
                         , [b].[Key]
                         , [c].[Value]
               FROM        @TestData [a]
               CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([a].[TestData]) [b]
               CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([b].[Value]) [c]
           ) AS [TestData]
INNER JOIN @SearchJson [srch]
    ON [srch].[Key] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = [TestData].[Key]
       AND [srch].[Value] = [TestData].[Value];
```

Which gives you the following results:

```
TestData
-----------------------------
{"Department":["QA"]}
{"Department":["DEV","QA"]}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This was helpful. I made some customization as per my requirement that search was supposed to be AND (not OR). Basically I looped through the search keys and found matching IDs in my Data table for the "First key-value" and then for second key-value onwards I removed all the non-matching Ids. That resulted only in the Ids which had ALL the key-values.